# Source path inside jupyter notebook to other files

Tags: python, directory, location, jupyter-notebook, cntk

From a jupyter notebook, I would like to set up a location to other files already uploaded in Jupyter.

Here’s the code, **I guess the line which is wrong is the first one:**

```
location = os.path.normpath('localhost:888/notebooks/project')

data = {
  'train': { 'file': 'train_modified.csv', 'location': 0 },
  'test': { 'file': 'test_modified.csv', 'location': 0 },
  'query': { 'file': 'query.csv', 'location': 1 },
  'slots': { 'file': 'train_labels.csv', 'location': 1 }
}

for item in data.values():
    location = locations[item['location']]
    path = os.path.join('..', location, item['file'])
    if os.path.exists(path):
        print("Reusing locally cached:", item['file'])
        # Update path
        item['file'] = path
    elif os.path.exists(item['file']):
        print("Reusing locally cached:", item['file'])
```

Running this code works fine.

However, when I continue working, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-c873a36fb4b7> in <module>
      1 # peek
----> 2 reader = create_reader(data['train']['file'], is_training=True)
      3 reader.streams.keys()

<ipython-input-23-81736f039ae7> in create_reader(path, is_training)
      4          intent_unused = C.io.StreamDef(field='S1', shape=num_intents, is_sparse=True),
      5          slot_labels   = C.io.StreamDef(field='S2', shape=num_labels,  is_sparse=True)
----> 6      )), randomize=is_training, max_sweeps = C.io.INFINITELY_REPEAT if is_training else 1)

~\Anaconda333\lib\site-packages\cntk\io\__init__.py in __init__(self, deserializers, max_samples, max_sweeps, randomization_window_in_chunks, randomization_window_in_samples, randomization_seed, trace_level, multithreaded_deserializer, frame_mode, truncation_length, randomize)
    191             config.randomization_window_in_samples = 0
    192 
--> 193         source = cntk_py.create_composite_minibatch_source(config)
    194         # transplant into this class instance
    195         self.__dict__ = source.__dict__

RuntimeError: Expected a sequence id at the offset 0, none was found.

[CALL STACK]
    > CreateDeserializer
    - Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::IDataReader::  SupportsDistributedMBRead (x3)
    - CreateDeserializer
    - CreateCompositeDataReader (x3)
    - CNTK::  UniversalLearner
    - CNTK::  CreateCompositeMinibatchSource
    - PyInit__cntk_py
    - PyCFunction_FastCallDict
    - PyObject_GetAttr
    - PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
    - PyObject_IsInstance
    - PyFunction_FastCallDict
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: @anky_91 any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [this](https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/Manual_How_to_create_user_minibatch_sources.html)

> Secondly, let’s assume that we have a data set in the following tab
>   seperated text format: * The first column is the sequence ID: e.g. 0
>   is the ID for sequecne 0; and 1 is the ID for sequence 1. * The second
>   column starts with symbol “|”. It is the feature named ‘x’ which is a
>   sparse representation for the words in our training data. * The third
>   column again starts with symbol “|”. It is our lable named ‘y’ which
>   is the one-hot representation of label.

Basically, i think your source data file is formatted incorrectly. You probably need to include a sequence id at the start of every line.

Comment: Have you checked out the link? It provides an example of how it should be done